# Full text timed out Exception

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using `freetext` in my query but I encounter this error just the first time i run the query. what's wrong?
I didn't have this problem in SQL server 2005.
I just have 10 records in my table.

```
Word breaking timed out for the full-text query string. This can happen if the wordbreaker took a long time to process the full-text query string, or if a large number of queries are running on the server. Try running the query again under a lighter load.
```

I'm using `SQL server 2008 version 10.0.1600.22 ((SQL_PreRelease).080709-1414 ).`

I have read about `wordbreaking dll` in the other forums but I don't kow what to do.
this is a simplified code of  my query:

```
select tbl_Workshops.Name as WorkshopName
from tbl_Workshops
 where (@Creteria='""' or freetext(tbl_Workshops.Name,@Creteria))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word breaker may be trying to verify signature, and unable to reach the service.

Try...

```
SELECT FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('VerifySignature');
GO
-- if 1, then turn off verify_signature
EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'verify_signature', 0;
GO
```

Comment: Could you tell me why I should turn off `verify_signature`?

Comment: @Raymond, If you are running the full text service on SQL Server 2005, a 45 second attempt to verify signature is performed, while your users are waiting for the full text query to return.
   
Since most web page timeouts are ~30 seconds, this causes the page to timeout.
  
See the following link, which recomends
  1. Upgrade to SQL Server 2008
  2. or Turn off verify signature
  
<http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlsecurity/thread/699221f0-a850-4f1d-b1db-a067a172f866/>

Comment: @BenTennen Thanks for the information. May need to fix your link to the MSDN article: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/699221f0-a850-4f1d-b1db-a067a172f866/sql-server-timeout-is-by-design-when-using-fulltext?forum=sqlsecurity

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the service called `SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher (INSTANCE)` is running and logs on using the same credentials as `SQL Server (INSTANCE)`